# Swift 2 - Check if an array contains a value from another smaller array

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift2, contains

I am trying to compare two arrays `(array1, array2)` and if a specific key value is contained in `array2`, the key value in `array1` that contains the array2 value needs to be printed out with its 'indexPath'.

The code I have almost works however, the app crashes because while going trough the keys, array2 goes out of range because it contains less indexes that the array1

How can I make the code look for matches if other array is smaller?

```
let array1 = [["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"], ["fff","ggg","hhh","matched","iii"], ["lll","mmm","nnn","ooo","ppp"], ["666","777","888","999","000"] ] //4 elements

let countArray1 = array1.enumerate()

let array2 = [["111","222"], ["333","444"], ["matched","555"]] // 3 elements


for (index, element) in countArray1{

    let containedValue = array1[index].contains(array2[index][0])

    if (containedValue) == true{

        print("The index of the contained value is: ????") //error

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you just need to know if a given value is present in both arrays?

Comment: just if a value in `array2` is contained in `array1`

Comment: Will the arrays always be 2D?

Comment: Yes, It will be always `[[String]]`. But the values inside are generated so elements can change. `Array2` can also be empty

Answer (score 0):

I would turn the smaller 2D array into a 1D array and then loop through the both dimensions of the bigger array and use `NSArray.contains:`

**DISCLAIMER**: this code is untested. @Community: if you stumble upon this and notice a mistake or something that can be better written, comment or edit. I use Obj-C more than Swift.

```
//convert 2D array to 1D
func from2Dto1D(array: NSArray) -> NSArray {
    var newArr = NSMutableArray()
    for (d1) in array {
        for (d2) in d1 {
            newArr.append(d2)
        }
    }
    return newArr as NSArray
}
func hasMatch(array1: NSArray, array2: NSArray) -> boolean {
    var bigger: NSArray
    var smaller: NSArray
    if (array1.count > array2.count){
        bigger = array1
        smaller = from2Dto1D(array2)
    }else{
        bigger = array2
        smaller = from2Dto1D(array1)
    }
    for (d1) in bigger{
        for (item) in d1 {
            if (smaller.contains(item)){
                print("Match found");
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could flatten out both the arrays and then enumerate them to check which index the objects match at.

```
let array1 = [["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"], ["fff","ggg","hhh","matched","iii"], ["lll","mmm","nnn","ooo","ppp"], ["666","777","888","999","000"] ] //4 elements

let array2 = [["111","222"], ["333","444"], ["matched","555"]] // 3 elements

let flat1 = Array(array1.flatten())       
let flat2 = Array(array2.flatten())

for (index1,object1) in flat1.enumerate() {
    for (index2,object2) in flat2.enumerate() {
        if object2 == object1 {
            print("index1 is: \(index1). Index 2 is \(index2)")
        }
    }
}
```